# Cannot open Facebook in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, facebook, phantomjs, casperjs

```
var picCounter = 1
    , url = 'https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152880761616654'


var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: false
, logLevel: 'debug'
, stepTimeout: 15000
})

casper.start()

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)')

casper.thenOpen(url, function() {
    console.log('in casper.start')
})

casper.wait(3000, function() { 
    console.log('capturing after start')
    console.log(this.getCurrentUrl())
})
casper.run()
```

here is the log

```
[info] [phantom] Starting...
[info] [phantom] Running suite: 3 steps
[debug] [phantom] opening url: https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=101528807616
16654, HTTP GET
[debug] [phantom] Navigation requested: url=https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v
=10152880761616654, type=Other, lock=true, isMainFrame=true
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: https://www.facebo
ok.com/video.php?v=10152880761616654
[debug] [phantom] Successfully injected Casper client-side utilities
in casper.start
[info] [phantom] Step 2/3: done in 151ms.
[info] [phantom] Step 3/3: done in 160ms.
[info] [phantom] wait() finished waiting for 3000ms.
capturing after start
about:blank
[info] [phantom] Done 3 steps in 3166ms
```

The `getCurrentUrl()` keeps returning `about:blank`.

Is there anything I can try to make it work? My goal is to go to some pages of status/photo/video etc, to get the comments from that page.

I am using CasperJS 1.0.4 and PhantomJS 1.8.2

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Scraping Facebook is not allowed. If you want the comments use the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were many bugs fixed from the 1.8.2 version onwards. I suggest you use PhantomJS 1.9.8. Also the 1.1.0-beta3 version of CasperJS has many improvements over 1.0.4 and is basically stable.

This might not be necessary, but using an Internet Explorer user agent string in PhantomJS is a bad idea, because the page might deliver JavaScript/CSS that is optimzed for IE which will not work in PhantomJS. An example is google. Always use the appropriate user agent such as this one for PhantomJS 1.x:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.41 Safari/535.1